# Not able to bind background attribute to a color

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-databinding

I am trying to change the background attribute of a TextView based on a method which returns boolean value.
So here's what my TextView looks like

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="model"
        type="fit.cure.meetingdisplay.MeetingModel" />
</data>
.....
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@{model.isAvailable() ? @color/colorAvailable : @color/colorUnavailable, default=@color/colorAvailable"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@{model.getAvailabilityText(), default=Available}"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Large.Inverse" />
```

The model is as follows -

```
public class MeetingModel {
    private boolean isAvailable = false;

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return isAvailable;
    }

    public void setAvailable(boolean available) {
        isAvailable = available;
    }

    public String getAvailabilityText() {
        if (isAvailable) {
            return "available";
        }
        return "unavailable";
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error while building the project -

```
error: '@{model.isAvailable() ? @color/colorAvailable : @color/colorUnavailable, default=@color/colorAvailable' is incompatible with attribute android:background (attr) reference|color.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: '@{model.isAvailable() ? @color/colorAvailable : @color/colorUnavailable, default=@color/colorAvailable' is incompatible with attribute android:background (attr) reference|color., sources=[/Volumes/Projects/Work/Clients/CureFit/MeetingDisplay/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:55], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

I am using `@color/colorAvailable` since it was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992211/use-databinding-library-to-set-background-color-resource-or-null) that it's possible to use it. I also tried the drawable approach using the following for the background value -

```
"@{model.isAvailable() ? @drawable/drawable_available : @drawable/drawable_unavailable, default=@drawable/drawable_available"
```

The drawables are defined in colors.xml as following -

```
<drawable name="drawable_available">@color/colorAvailable</drawable>
<drawable name="drawable_unavailable">@color/colorUnavailable</drawable>
```

Still getting the same error. Strangely the default value works in both the cases.

So, is it something am I doing wrong here, or is it not possible to bind the background attribute at all (I don't think it's impossible though).

Comment: I don't think it support `elvis operator` as explained by the error message ` is incompatible with attribute android:background (attr) reference|color.`...

Comment: @ariefbayu but it has been used in the following answer and it's working - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33065020/1079901

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the perfect example on why autocomplete is so important these days and why it would make our days better if it would work better in `xmls`. You're simply missing the closing bracket:

`android:background="@{model.isAvailable() ? @color/colorAvailable : @color/colorUnavailable, default=@color/colorAvailable}"`

Comment: :-O :-O *facepalm*

Comment: I had the same feeling, it took me some time to spot it. Btw, the bracket is missing in the `android:textAppearance` too. Autocomplete FTW

Comment: I had the exactly same problem now with the exactly same context. lol