# Is there a way to set drawableTint of TextView using viewmodel?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewmodel

I want to set the color of a compound drawable programmatically. I think the best solution would be to use a `ViewModel`.

This is what I have so far:

```xml
...
    <data>
        <import type="androidx.core.content.ContextCompat"/>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.pezcraft.myapplication.MainViewModel" />
    </data>
...
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewState"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="text"
                    app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_circle"
                    app:drawableTint="@{ContextCompat.getColor(context, viewmodel.colorState)}"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewIP" />
```

```java
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<Integer> colorState;

    public MainViewModel() {
        colorState = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Integer> getColorState() {
        return colorState;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work when building...

> [databinding] {"msg":"Cannot find a setter for \u003candroid.widget.TextView app:drawableTint\u003e that accepts parameter type \u0027int\u0027\n\nIf a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992211/use-databinding-library-to-set-background-color-resource-or-null

Comment: Use LevelDrawable

Comment: @Style-7 I cannot set a level for text views. Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Level is a state of your view. Just set a level for set a color.